# What is the most popular MMO game that has an out-of-game API

Tags: android

World of Warcraft is off the table, because of the "WOW Glider Lawsuit" of 2008. Also see: [Where is Blizzards official World of Warcraft API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473851/where-is-blizzards-official-world-of-warcraft-api)

But, what is the most popular (in terms of usership) MMO Game that does allow programmers to develop out-of-game things (like an Android app).

Comment: wow does have a community api that can be accessed for game information about character realm status auction house data among other things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EVE online has an API [Here](http://www.eveonline.com/api/doc/)